Is the Hilbert class field of a Galois extension still GaloisÉ
Let $K/E$ be a finite Galois field extension of global fields, and $L$ be the Hilbert class field of $K$. Is $L/E$ still Galois?
I proved it myself by this:
Let $\sigma:L\hookrightarrow\bar E$ be an $E$-embedding into a fixed algebraic closure of $E$. Then $\sigma(L)$ is the Hilbert class field of $\sigma(K)$.
Since $K/E$ is Galois, $\sigma(K)$ does not depend on $\sigma$, and so does $\sigma(L)$ since the Hilbert class field is unique. Thus $\sigma(L)$ is always the same, so $L/E$ is Galois.
I can't find an error in my proof, but I didn't hear anything about this proposition. Is it right, or did I do anything wrong?

There does not seem to be anything wrong in your proof.  But another way of looking at it  is that the Hilbert class field $L$ is a Galois extension of $K$; since $L/K$ is Galois and $K/E$ is Galois, it follows that $L/E$ is also Galois.

There is a typo in your post -- it should be $\sigma(K)$ does not depend on $\sigma$, ...

@AnuradhaNarasimhan This is generally not true that if $L/K$ is Galois and $K/E$ is Galois, then $L/E$ is Galois. For example, $E=\mathbb{Q}$, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$. Since $i\sqrt[4]{2}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, $L/E$ is not Galois.

Yes, you are correct, $L$ need not be normal over $E$ (as your example shows) (though it is finite and separable over $E$).  So we cannot conclude by my argument that $L/E$ is also Galois.
